# Some doubtes about maven tags?

Tags: maven, build

i am new to maven though  worked on ant a lot.After going thru http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html, i am bit confused.
i have two basic questions:-

1)whats the difference between mirror url and  pluginRepository url. As my understanding both url defines the url from where repository
needs to be downloaded

2)whats the diefference b/w repository and pluginRepository?

3)what actually profile is? as per my understanding its a goal which we want to execute. For example:- when we do mvn install, install is  already
 defined  profile by maven. Is n't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me start with a basic difference in Maven.

[In general repositories are containers which can store two major types of artifacts.](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Repositories)

1. The first are artifacts that are used as dependencies of other artifacts.
2. The other type of artifact is plugins. Maven plugins are themselves a special type of artifact. Because of this, plugin repositories may be separated from other repositories

Usually there will not made a difference between pluginRepositories and *usual* repositories, but technically it's possible.

Now to your first question:

It is possible to declare a repository inside the project which means to put the repository definition into the pom file which is [bad practice](http://blog.sonatype.com/people/2009/02/why-putting-repositories-in-your-poms-is-a-bad-idea/).

The mirror setting is usually used to mirror all request from the defined repositories into a defined URL (see mirror settings). In practice delegate all request to a particular URL which is usually a URL of a repository manager.

Now we came to your third question.

A profile has nothing to do with a goal and nothing with `mvn install`. The call `mvn install` calls the [maven build life cyclce](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) which will run all life cycle phase after another. A [profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) can be best *translated* with a if-statement. You can activate a profile on command line like this:

```
mvn -Pdev install

mvn -Prun-its verify
```

which is a kind of condition in you pom.